# Is there a way to create a shuffle mode with html5 audio player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a shuffle mode for multiple playlists with the native html5 audio player.  I am not that great with javascript i am more of a web designer and not developer. I cannot find anything on creating a shuffle mode online so I figured I would ask the question here and see if someone can help.  I have multiple playlists and would like to create a shuffle mode for each individual playlist and load it into the one audio player.  Is this possible with javascript or jquery?  Here is my code that I have for my audio playlists.

```
 <audio id="player" controls="controls">
    <source src="#" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="#" type="audio/mp3">
 </audio>

 <ul class="playlist">
     <li><button class="music-button" onclick='track1()'>Track1</button </li>
     <li><button class="music-button" onclick='track2()'>Track2</button </li>
     <li><button class="music-button" onclick='track3()'>Track3</button </li>
 </ul>

 <ul class="playlist2">
     <li><button class="music-button" onclick='track1()'>Track1</button </li>
     <li><button class="music-button" onclick='track2()'>Track2</button </li>
     <li><button class="music-button" onclick='track3()'>Track3</button </li>
 </ul>

 <script>
      function track1(){

      var player=document.getElementById('player');
      var sourceOgg=document.getElementById('player');
      var sourceMp3=document.getElementById('player');

      sourceOgg.src='url.ogg';
      sourceMp3.src='url.mp3';

       player.load();
       player.play(); 
 }

      function track2(){

      var player=document.getElementById('player');
      var sourceOgg=document.getElementById('player');
      var sourceMp3=document.getElementById('player');

      sourceOgg.src='url.ogg';
      sourceMp3.src='url.mp3';

       player.load();
       player.play(); 
 }

      function track3(){

      var player=document.getElementById('player');
      var sourceOgg=document.getElementById('player');
      var sourceMp3=document.getElementById('player');

      sourceOgg.src='url.ogg';
      sourceMp3.src='url.mp3';

       player.load();
       player.play(); 
 }

 </script>
```

Comment: I have tried creating an array for the list but it only shuffles the list it obviously doesn't play the songs.  I have tried creating an array for the functions but not sure it doesn't fire and I don't know if this is even possible.  I feel like I have tried just about everything.  Not sure why everyone keeps clicking the down arrow next to this question maybe this forum is a bad place to ask code questions for people just starting with javascript.  I have been reasearching this non-stop for like a week now and can't find any answers.  Maybe time to give up, arrays not working for me idk why.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 3 months old, but someone might have use for this. I created a JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/vkMqR/1404/

```
<audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<div id="playing">
</div>

var audio;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;

var musicarr = ["http://www.archive.org/download/CanonInD_261/CanoninD.mp3",
                "http://www.archive.org/download/MoonlightSonata_755/Beethoven-MoonlightSonata.mp3",
                "http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3",
                "http://www.archive.org/download/onclassical-quality-wav-audio-files-of-classical-music/onclassical_demo_demicheli_geminiani_pieces_allegro-in-f-major_small-version_64kb.mp3",
                "http://www.archive.org/download/onclassical-quality-wav-audio-files-of-classical-music/onclassical_demo_elysium_anonymous-elysium_the-young-false-man_small-version_live-and_restored_64kb.mp3",
                "http://www.archive.org/download/onclassical-quality-wav-audio-files-of-classical-music/onclassical_demo_ensemble-la-tempesta_porpora_iii-notturno_iii-lezione_live_small-version_64kb.mp3",
                "http://www.archive.org/download/onclassical-quality-wav-audio-files-of-classical-music/onclassical_demo_roccato_anonymous-roccato_riflessi_small-version_64kb.mp3"
               ];
shuffle(musicarr);

init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('audio');
    audio[0].volume = .40;
    len = musicarr.length;

    run(musicarr[current], audio[0]);

    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
        }
        run(musicarr[current],audio[0]);
    });
}

function run(link, player){
        player.src = link;
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();
        $('#playing').html("<ul><li><a>" + link+ "</a></li></ul>");     
}

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
```

I took the code from http://www.lastrose.com/html5-audio-video-playlist and removed the playlist and used an array with track links which I shuffle on page load. The ended eventlistener will load the next track when the current is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try creating an array of all the tracks you have, and then try shuffling the array? Here's a great StackOverflow resource for shuffling arrays: [Fisher Yates Shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Comment: would the html5 audio player know when the last song is over with and then play the next track I took a look at the code but like I said not great with javascript so im not really sure how to implement this.  Can you give me an example that would help.  Thank you for responding.

Comment: Once you've shuffled an array, you can keep on popping elements off of the array. Each element you pop off is the song to play. You can continue popping these elements off while the array is not empty. Once its empty, you can shuffle the array again and start over.

Comment: As I suspected this will not play the next song in the array I may be doing something wrong but not sure as I have limited experience with javascript I only know the basics if there is anyone out there who can help I would really appreciate it.  Some kind of example would really help.